# Derivation of equivalence of molecular and atomic orbitals

Tags: matrix-elements

Intuitively, it seems quite reasonable that n atomic orbitals produce n molecular orbitals.

I'm curious about how this can be proven from the generalised eigenvalue equation for the AO coefficients. Why are there n eigenfunctions for a n by n hamiltonian matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Intuitively, it seems quite reasonable that n atomic orbitals produce n molecular orbitals. I'm curious about how this can be proved from the representation of the hamiltonian as an n-by-n matrix.

Start from some n-by-n matrix for the Hamiltonian, which is written in the basis of the atomic orbitals. In this basis, the matrix is not diagonal, which is why we go to a different basis (the molecular orbitals).

The n-by-n hamiltonian matrix:
$$
H
$$
is diagonalized by applying an n-by-n transformation matrix $T$ like this:
$$
h = T^\dagger HT\;,
$$
where $h$ is an n-by-n diagonal matrix.

Each column of the matrix $T$ defines a molecular orbital as written in the atomic orbital basis. There are n columns, so there are n molecular orbitals.

For example, the first molecular orbital $\chi^{(1)}$ is:
$$
\chi^{(1)} = \sum_{j=1}^n T_{j1}\phi_j\;,
$$
where the $\phi_j$ are atomic orbitals.

For example the nth molecular orbital $\chi^{(n)}$ is:
$$
\chi^{(n)} = \sum_{j=1}^n T_{jn}\phi_j\;.
$$

And similarly, for all the orbitals in between.